# Cleaning a keyboard with water spots or some black spots on it

Tags: piano, keyboard, instrument-cleaning

[image: Yamaha psr e463 with these black spots]I have a synth action keyboard which I'm planning to sell. As I'm cleaning my keyboard, I notice some black spots on it (possibly water spots??? I don't know how). Does anyone know what this exactly is and how I can remove them?

Comment: It would be helpful to have a photo showing the spots you're trying to clean.

Comment: If that's plastic you can try acetone (no!! Do not do that, it's a joke). Have you tried something already? Like an humid tissue? Is it plastic? Wood?

Comment: I've tried just water, shampoo and water , a bit of white vinegar, dishwashing liquid with water .... nothings worked :( Yea, it's plastic

Comment: Where are the spots? All I notice is a natural(-looking) speck pattern on the plastic. For all I know, the keyboard arrived in the store this way.

Comment: Have you tried just rubbing the area with a dry microfiber cloth? Looks like the spotting I get when I accidentally get cleaning spray on an area and don’t wipe it off.

Comment: @ToddWilcox you might be right, it does look like cleaning spray spots. It's very sporadic, so not on the entire keyboard. Is there anyway to get it off?

Answer (score 3):

Yamaha keyboards of that type [PK/PSR etc] are usually painted plastic, certainly any metallic silver/grey sections - even the soft push-buttons.
I don't know of any that are intentionally patterned like that - but it's been 20 years since I worked there.

That looks to me like it's been sprayed or splashed with something that has actually damaged the paint surface, but not enough to go right through it [it's almost certainly black plastic underneath]. I very much doubt you could clean it off, it's already 'off'.

The entire top shell will be one single moulding, oversprayed in one single colour. Highlights would then be screen-printed over, or masked like the plexi-glass section you can see a hint of at the left, which is likely painted on the rear to give a high gloss face.

If the entire painted surface surface shows the same markings, it's an intentional pattern. If it's randomly varied over the surface, it's damaged.
I simply cannot tell from the pictures on https://uk.yamaha.com/en/products/musical_instruments/keyboards/portable_keyboards/psr-e463/index.html

This is what it looks like when it's worn off completely…

[image]

Comment: As @ToddWilcox mentioned above, I do think it's cleaning spray spots. I've tried everything from shampoo to water to vinegar to dry cloth. Nothing's worked. So repainting it is my only option?

Comment: It can't be repainted. It's sprayed like a car, before it's assembled, before the screen printing & plexi are added. I think you're just going to have to accept it's damaged.

Comment: Do you think it's going to significantly lower the valuation of the keyboard? It's pretty new and works very well.

Comment: It's going to affect it, for sure. New these seem to be about $£€ 280, 2nd hand 150 - idk how much someone would want off that for cosmetic damage, but valuations aren't my specialty.